# I am trying to test strings for the existence of substrings, wondering whether possible with "contains" or need something else?

Tags: c#

I use MVC3, C#, .NET4

I have a pattern ie

```
"irc:tl:tr,sp"
```

I am only interested in

```
"irc:tl:sp" bit.
```

However a straight

```
string.Contains("irc:tl:sp")
```

will return false due to presenvr of "tr", so I need something like a wildcard ie

```
string.Contains("irc:tl:*sp")
```

Is there a way of achieving this wildcard approach or am I needing Regex?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Regex.IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, @"irc:tl:.*,sp")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions, but if you just want to use a simple wildcard pattern, my [NString library](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/NString) has a [`MatchesWildcard`](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/NString/blob/master/NString/StringExtensions.cs#L158) extension method to do just that:

```
bool result = "irc:tl:tr,sp".MatchesWildcard("irc:tl:*sp"); // true
```

Comment: Love the class that you have created, but I decided to go with Regex, because of the extra features. Thanks again